# Why doesn't react-router-dom useParams hook work within Context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I've got a context shared amongst a group of profile pages. The context is responsible for loading and setting the user's profile from a database, like so:

```
const Profile = props => {
    const { userProfile } = useContext(ProfileContext);
    return userProfile && (
        <div className="profile-container">
            ...stuff
        </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

...routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <main className="main-container">
        <Switch>
            ...other routes
            <ProfileContextProvider>
                <Route path="/profile/:id" exact component={Profile} />
                <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings} />
            </ProfileContextProvider>
        </Switch>                       
    </main>
    <Footer />
</BrowserRouter>
```

The context itself is very simple:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProfileContext = React.createContext({
    userProfile: {},
    setUserProfile: () => {}
});

ProfileContext.displayName = "ProfileContext";

const ProfileContextProvider = props => {
    const { id } = useParams(); //always undefined!
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, []);
    
    const loadData = async () => {
        ...api call to load data
    };
    
    return (
        <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ 
            userProfile,
            setUserProfile
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </ProfileContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default ProfileContextProvider;
```

However, that use of useParams() in there doesn't work. The "id" is always undefined. If I move this useParams() usage to the Profile component itself, it works fine. This does me no good, because I need to make a decision about the route, when loading data in the context, before I load all of Profile. I need it to work in the context!

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The context provider, or `useParams` hook needs to be rendered/accessed lower in the ReactTree to the `Route` with the path with the route match param you're trying to access. It won't work when the `ProfileContextProvider` is higher in the ReactTree. What might work though is providing a callback that routed components can call when they are mounted.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, figures as much when looking at the routes...but was hoping it'd still be in context as the context itself is instantiated at the component level. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

Your ProfileContextProvider is outside the route that defines the "id" param.... this cant work.

Answer (score 0):

Context is itself different management and query param should props from the page to context set variable then it works